# Tomcat 8.5.31 no puede abrir su propio log

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, glassfish, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un proyecto en `Java` y le cambie el `contenedor de Servlet` `Glassfish` por `Tomcat`.

El problema es que no funciona `Tomcat`, tira el siguiente error:

> Starting Tomcat process... Waiting for Tomcat... Starting of Tomcat
>   failed.
>   /home/educacion/NetBeansProjects/hotelre/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045:
>   Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed. See the server log for
>   details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)

En otra ventana de log llamada `Apache Tomcat or TomEE` tira estos errores:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/educacion/Descargas/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/logs/catalina.2018-05-09.log
>   (Permiso denegado)

Hay un problema en el archivo `build-impl.xml` que no se como solucionarlo:

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Trate de darle los permisos pero cuando voy a la carpeta no encuentro ningun archivo. La carpeta esta vacia.

Gracias.

Comment: crea el archivo log a mano y ve que pasa, pero si no existen los archivos, posiblemente el tomcat este mal instalado

Answer (score 0):

Trata de darle permisos a la carpeta del tomcat para tu usuario, regularmente la ruta es:

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat (Tu Version)"
```

Comment: Estoy con Linux. Y eso ya lo intente y no funciono.

Comment: Y cuando se instalo tomcat, se creo un grupo especifico para este servicio? si es así asegúrate que también tu usuario pertenezca a dicho grupo

Comment: Gracias. No se ni idea. Estoy muy enfermo con este tema de Tomcat.  ¿Se crea un grupo nuevo ? Se supone que Netbeans deberia arreglarlo o no. No puede ser que tenga que estar configurando, cuando voy a programar.

Comment: El usuario del OS que inicia el proceso de Netbeans debe tener permiso para iniciar el proceso de Tomcat. Netbeans es una instancia de la JVM nada más, no te va a arreglar nada.

Comment: ¿Instalaste tomcat desde un paquete de la distribución que estás usando? Podrías probar descargar uno desde la propia web de tomcat, descomprimirlo en un directorio donde tengas permisos y hacerlo andar desde ahí. Tu problema huele a permisos. No olvides parar el servicio del tomcat que instaló tu paquete.